# Object not loading on target image with Unity and Vuforia

Tags: image, dataset, target, vuforia

I'm trying to put an object over the target image but it is not loading over target image.

I'm using unity 2018.3.0f2 and Vuforia version 7.5.26. I'm following a course where he sets the datasets property to like this!

[image]

But in the new version this option is not available. I also searched a lot on vuforia documentation but I didn't find a solution. Can anyone suggest what is the right way to load object into the target image with new version of vuforia?

I followed these steps:

1. Created a license key with my project name
2. Captured a photo with my mobile and uploaded it to the database of my project in Vuforia (My image got 5 Star rating there)
3. Downloaded the unity file of my database
4. Imported the Database unity file.
5. Replaced the unity default camera with Vuforia AR Camera.
6. Added the target image to hierarchy and pasted the license key that I got from Vuforia into my unity project
7. Added a 3D model as a child of the target image.

Comment: Please provide the detail of implementation what you have tried.

Comment: @Vebbie: that has now been added to the question.